# Terminate a loop and retain results so far

Tags: r

I am curious if there is a way in R to do some function which runs either forever or for sone long time which you can matter terminate without losing the results.

For example, say I would like to fit lots of linear models to some randomly generated data like so

```
dat <-list() 
for (i in 1:1e99){
x <- 1:10
y <- cumsum(runif(10))
dat[[i]] <- lm(y~x) 
}
```

I would like to leave my computer for a long time and when I return, I will stop the function. I would like to keep all of the models that have been built. 
Basically I want it to do as much as it can before I get back and then not lose its progress when I go to stop it.

Does anyone know a way of accomplishing this in R?

Answer (score 1):

You run the loop then hit the stop button when you get back.

Comment: @user5364303 be warned on some occasions it won't work, and you'll have to wait for end or kill the session.